# FOR loop issue in Python. Last sub list not counted

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

The code below loops only three times but there are four lists it should use:

```
data_set_01 = [['A', 1, 0, 'N'], ['A', 2, 1, 'E'], ['A', 3, 2, 'S'], ['A', 4, 3, 'W']]
```

It only does the first three lists and then breaks but it needs to do all four lists in data_set_01. I can't see a problem with my code unfortunately so i don't know what to fix.

```
for data in list(data_set_00):
    if data_set_00[0][0]:
        size = combine
        data_set_01[0][1] = -175
        data_set_01[0][2] = -100

        data_set_01[1][1] = -50
        data_set_01[1][2] = -30

        data_set_01[2][1] = 70
        data_set_01[2][2] = 30

        data_set_01[3][1] = 150
        data_set_01[3][2] = 175

    if data_set_01[0][0]:
        pu()
        data_set_01[0][3] = setheading(90)
        goto(data_set_01[0][1],data_set_01[0][2])
        NBC()
        home()
        if data_set_01[0][1]:
            pu()
            data_set_01[1][3] = setheading(0)
            goto(data_set_01[1][1],data_set_01[1][2])
            NBC()
            home()
            if data_set_01[0][2]:
                pu()
                data_set_01[2][3] = setheading(270)
                goto(data_set_01[2][1],data_set_02[2][2])
                NBC()
                home()
                if data_set_01[0][3]:
                    pu()
                    data_set_01[3][3] = setheading(180)
                    goto(data_set_01[3][1],data_set_01[3][2])
                    NBC()
                    home()
                break
```

Comment: How is `data_set_00` defined? If it is like `data_set_01`, which is already a  `list`, then there is no need to use the `list()` function. Also, I don't see you using `data` anywhere in your loop. It would appear that you should pick a different loop variable at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to nitpick but it seems you have

```
for data in list( data_set_00 ):
```

Did you mean to say **`data_set_00`** has 4 lists or did you use the wrong data set to iterate through in your **`for`** loop?

Comment: I was referring to the data_set_01 list not data_set_00. It's using the lists in data_set_01. Data_set_00 holds data_set_01 along with other data sets.

Comment: This kind of posts are comments, as they do not provide a valid answer to the question.

Comment: you're right @GuillaumeFache I didn't know how to ask him a question w/o commenting since I can't yet.  I can delete this if you think that's what's best!

Comment: That's the problem with these limits, and I do not know what is the proper reaction to this. My suggestion would be to leave it as it is (if it realy needs to be deleted moderators will do so). My comment was more to inform you